# Is Reactive Extensions evaluating too many times?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How many times is Reactive Extensions supposed to evaluate its various operators?

I have the following test code:

```
var seconds = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("{0} Generated Data", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

var split = seconds
    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("{0}  Split/Branch received Data", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

var merged = seconds
    .Merge(split)
    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("{0}   Received Merged data", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

var pipeline = merged.Subscribe();
```

I expect this to write "Generated Data" once every five seconds. It then hands off that data to both the 'split' stream which writes "Split/Branch received Data", and to the 'merged' stream which writes "Received Merged data". Last, because the 'merged' stream is also receiving from the 'split' stream, it receives the data second time and writes "Received Merged data" a second time. (The order it writes some of them in is not particularly relevant)

But the output I am getting is this:

```
8:29:56 AM Generated Data
8:29:56 AM Generated Data
8:29:56 AM  Split/Branch received Data
8:29:56 AM   Received Merged data
8:29:56 AM   Received Merged data
8:30:01 AM Generated Data
8:30:01 AM Generated Data
8:30:01 AM  Split/Branch received Data
8:30:01 AM   Received Merged data
8:30:01 AM   Received Merged data
```

It is writing "Generaged Data" twice. To my understanding, The number of downstream observers that are subscribed to the "seconds" IObservable should not affect the number of times that "Generated Data" writes (which should be ONCE), but it does. Why?

*NOTE* I am using the stable release v1.0 SP1 of reactive extensions in a .Net Framework 3.5 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, they choose that approach to allow each subscriber to get its values at the same interval from their initial subscription.  Consider how your alternate Interval would work:

```
0s - First subscriber subscribes
5s - Value: 0
8s - Second subscriber subscribes
10s - Value: 1
15s - Value: 2
17s - Unsubscribe both
```

What you end up with is something like this:

```
First  -----0----1----2-|
Second         --1----2-|
```

In this case, the two observers have **noticeably** different results depending on whether or not there is any other observer already attached.  As it is implemented, `Interval` gives the same experience to each subscriber regardless of order or past subscribers.

All that said, you can "convert" `Interval` to the behavior you describe by adding `.Publish().RefCount()` when creating the `seconds` observable.

Comment: `.Publish().RefCount()` did the trick, Thanks. I understand your explanation and its necessity, but I find this default behavior to be not particularly useful for most scenarios in which I would want to use Reactive Extensions.

Comment: This behavior is the result of very careful design :-).

If mere creation of a source were to imply its activation (a so-called "hot" model), messages can be missed between the time of creation and the time of subscription. Notice for Task<T> this isn't a problem since at most one value has to be cached for "late subscribers" (i.e. ContinueWith callbacks). For event streams, you can't cache values; doing so is asking for an OutOfMemoryException.

Asti's answer below draws a useful analogy with IEnumerable. Another analogy is .NET events; two += calls can result in two "sessions".

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems like it might be nice sometimes if sequences were multicasted at every step, if it were that way it wouldn't allow you to have the rich composition that Rx allows for.

To think of it another way, 
`IObservable` is the push-based dual of `IEnumerable`.
`IEnumerable` has the property of lazy evaluation - the values aren't computed until you start moving through the `Enumerator`. Rx sequences are composed lazily and finally a Subscribe() (the Observable equivalent of For-Each) realises the sequence.

This way you can stop the pipeline at all stages simply by un-subscribing from the last stage, allowing you to have fire and forget behavior without going through the nightmare of managing individual subscriptions.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you. That means a lot coming from you.

Comment: IEnumerable does not use lazy evaluation, LINQ uses lazy evaluation. IEnumerable just embodies the concept of traversing a collection, and then restarting back to the beginning of that collection. LINQ builds on this and consequently can restart its progress through the collection at any time thanks to IEnumerable. 

Conversely, IObservable just provides a way to subscribe to data, and provides no 'contract' that you can restart that data. Its a coincidence of being able to be built from an IEnumerable that you can have data restart itself, and an unspecified coincidence at that.

Comment: LINQ =/= IEnumerable. LINQ is a set of language extensions which the compiler translates to certain implementations of monads. IEnumerable is by definition lazy - you do not compute a value until it is pulled from the sequence.

Comment: Saying IEnumerable is lazy is like saying an array is lazy because you only access the array as you need it. Both just provide access mechanisms; Array's provide access via an index into the Array and Enumerators provide forward-only traversal (and Reset). LINQ makes the choice to be lazy, and indeed certain operators (like OrderBy) actually abandon their lazy evaluation (once they themselves are evaluation) because they must evaluate the entire enumeration immediately to compute their result.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, here's a brainteaser for you, illustrating Asti's analogy with lazily evaluated enumerable sequences:

```
private static Random s_rand = new Random();

public static IEnumerable<int> Rand()
{
    while (true)
        yield return s_rand.Next();
}

public static void Main()
{
    var xs = Rand();

    var res = xs.Zip(xs, (l, r) => l == r).All(b => b);

    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

If you Zip a random sequence with itself, do you expect all pairs of elements to be the same (i.e. resulting in the code above to run forever)? Or, do you expect the code to terminate and print false for some reason?

(Creating the analogous observable code is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: [spoiler] The `All` operator will break when its predicate evaluates to false. Since xs is lazy, the `Zip` is guaranteed to pair up two different values, resulting in the selector always returning false - hence causing enumeration to stop on the first value.  To get the equivalent of multicast in Observables, we'd have to use `xs = Memoize(Rand())` - which would result in the program running forever. [/spoiler]

Comment: Rx equivalent: `var xs = Observable.Repeat(0).Select(_ => s_rand.Next());`
...
`res.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: I feel this exemplifies the fact that none of the Reactive Extensions features distinguish between live, non-restartable data and cached, restartable data (IEnumerable). You have no idea when using an operator (i.e. `Do()`) if the source of the data is one or the other. Yet the default `Subscribe()` implementation appears to choose the latter, and thus it catches you off guard when you first encounter it. I am thankful though that the development team realized the need for live data and at least added `.Publish().RefCount()`

Comment: @MattG I added a new answer because the comment was too large.

Answer (score 0):

From an object-oriented perspective, it's normal for thinking about streams to be grounded in the interfaces that define `Observables`/`Enumerables`. If you can ignore the fact that there's a convenience method called Reset defined on the Enumerator - Enumerables are functionally speaking `f -> g -> value?`. An enumerable is essentially a function you call to get the enumerator which is essentially a function you keep calling until there are no more values to be returned.

Similarly an Observable is simply be defined as `f(g) -> g(h) -> h(value?)` - it's a function you supply with the function you want called when there is a value.

This is why makes no sense to describe an enumerable or observable as anything but a set of functions defined in a certain way so they can be composed - the contracts are to ensure the ability to compose computations.

Whether they're live, cached or lazy are implementation details which may be abstracted elsewhere - and while I certainly don't disagree that these details are important it's more important to focus on the functional nature of it.

A sequence which is a database query or a directory listing has the same `IEnumerable` interface as a pre-computed set of values (like an Array). It's up to the code which finally consumes the sequence to make that distinction. If you can get used to the notion that it's a way to compose higher order functions, you'll find it easier to model a problem using Rx or Ix.

Comment: I agree. Observables and Enumerables are just traversal mechanisms that call functions (that presumably return data). The implementation details, i.e. LINQ and Reactive Extensions, make the choices about lazy, live, or cached. LINQ chooses to allow lazy evaulation. Reactive Extensions makes the choice that it assumes Observables are cached data, and requires the user to take extra steps (`.Publish().RefCount()`) to use them as a live source instead. The problem is that the Observable contract does not define it as either Cached or Live data, but Rx assumed the former.