# Reactive Extensions Do operator fires more times than I expect

Tags: system.reactive

Can anyone tell me what causes this seemingly odd Do behavior in the following code? I would expect the Do handler to be called once per OnNext.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class WhyDoesDoActSoWierd
{
    [Test]
    public void ButWhy()
    {
        var doCount = 0;
        var observable = new Subject<int>();
        var stream = observable.Do( x => doCount++ );
        var subs =
            (from x in stream
             where x % 2 == 1
             from y in stream
             where y % 2 == 0
                   && y == x + 1
             select new { x, y })
                .Subscribe( x => Console.WriteLine( "{0}, {1}", x.x, x.y ) );

        observable.OnNext( 1 );
        // doCount == 1
        observable.OnNext( 2 );
        // doCount == 3
        observable.OnNext( 3 );
        // doCount == 5
        observable.OnNext( 4 );
        // doCount == 8
        observable.OnNext( 5 );
        // doCount == 11
        observable.OnNext( 6 );
        // doCount == 15
        Assert.AreEqual( 6, doCount );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour here is perfectly normal. The reason is that you don't just have one subscription, you have many. And because of the cartesian product between the two observables in the query you have a larger number of `Do` than you might otherwise expect.

Let's look at an alternative (but similar) query to yours.

```
    var doCountX = 0;
    var doCountY = 0;

    Action dump = () =>
        Console.WriteLine("doCountX = {0}, doCountY = {1}", doCountX, doCountY);

    var observable = new Subject<int>();

    var streamX = observable.Do(x => doCountX++);
    var streamY = observable.Do(x => doCountY++);

    var query =
        from x in streamX
        from y in streamY
        select new { x, y };

    query.Subscribe(z => Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", z.x, z.y));

    dump();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        observable.OnNext(i);
        dump();
    }
```

The output from this is:

```
doCountX = 0, doCountY = 0
doCountX = 1, doCountY = 0
1, 2
doCountX = 2, doCountY = 1
1, 3
2, 3
doCountX = 3, doCountY = 3
1, 4
2, 4
3, 4
doCountX = 4, doCountY = 6
1, 5
2, 5
3, 5
4, 5
doCountX = 5, doCountY = 10
1, 6
2, 6
3, 6
4, 6
5, 6
doCountX = 6, doCountY = 15
```

There's the initial dump of `doCountX = 0, doCountY = 0` which is to be expected as this call to `dump()` occurs before any calls to `OnNext`.

But when we get the first call to `OnNext` we don't get a value produced by the query because the second `streamY` observable hasn't yet been subscribed to.

It's only when `OnNext` is called the second time do we get a value from the query which happens to be the first `OnNext` value paired with the second. Now this also creates a new subscriptions to `streamY`, waiting for the next value.

So we've now got the first two values from `streamX` waiting for the next value from the sequence. So when `OnNext(3)` is called we get two results.

Each time this happens you can see the number of `Do` calls incrementing `doCountY` just keep going up.

In fact, given this very plain `SelectMany` query the formula is:

```
doCountY = n * (n - 1) / 2
```

So with 6 values produced via `OnNext` you get `doCountY` equal to `6 * 5 / 2` or `15`.

Running with 10 values gives `10 * 9 / 2` or `45` values.

So a `SelectMany` in fact does many more subscriptions than you might think. This is often why you would generally only use it to chain together observables that only produce a single value each to prevent the exponential explosion of subscriptions.

Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, this is what I suspected, although I can not see why one would want this behavior. The subscriptions behind the scenes are an implementation detail which I would not expect causing this sort of behavior with an innocently placed Do (in my case, I wanted to log before the SelectMany). My problem here is that I only started toying with Rx the other week, so I'm a total rookie. Question: what is the correct way to wire up a subscription that reacts when it has found two related pieces of data in a single, infinite stream? :)

Comment: @Bergius - Your `Do` didn't cause this issue. The `SelectMany` did. Your `Do` just uncovered it. It is the correct behaviour for a `SelectMany`. You might want to look at `Join`, `Window`, `Merge`, or `CombineLatest` to see how to relate two (or more) streams. It's likely that `Join` or `Window` are what you want, but they can be difficult to understand - they both join based on events occurring within a window of time or coincidentally.

Comment: I soon realized that my comment was simply a result of ignorance :). I will have a look at the other operators in my quest to understand Rx. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

As an aside to Enigmativity's well fleshed-out answer, there are 2 things going on here:

1. Observables like Enumerables compose lazily. 
   Just like you wouldn't expect any combinator in an enumerable query to be evaluated until your move through the enumerator, you should expect that consumers will see the all combinators evaluated for that pipeline, as many times as the number of observers subscribing to the pipeline. 
   In short, `x <- stream, y <- stream` already makes it twice.
2. The comprehension is rewritten as:

   ```
       stream1.Where(x => x % 2 == 1)
              .SelectMany(x => stream2
                               .Where(y => y % 2 == 0 && y == x + 1)
                               .Select(y => new { x, y })
                               );
   ```

   For every value of x received, you will make a subscription to all the values of the stream which match the predicate - which becomes a lot. Query comprehensions are generally de-sugared as `SelectMany`/`Join`/`GroupBy` - most of Rx you'll practically end up using might be better expressed in terms of other operators - such as `Merge` or `Zip` or even `Join`.

There's a question which is extremely similar to the one you've just asked: 
**[Is Reactive Extensions evaluating too many times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319204/is-reactive-extensions-evaluating-too-many-times)**

There's a bit of a discussion on why this is the expected behavior in Rx.